# Como iniciar um EditText como nulo?

Tags: android

Eu quero que, quando o usuário marcar uma *RadioButton*, uma *EditText* que já foi iniciada como nula, apareça, mas eu não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Essa *EditText* é declarada num XML ou é criada por código? Explique o que quer dizer com *"EditText que ja foi iniciada como nula"*

Comment: Essa EdtiText ja foi disposta num arquivo XML, ja foi chamada no JAVA, e agora queria fazer com que, essa EditText ja inicie como nula e, quando o usuario clicar numa RadioButton, ele aparecesse

Comment: Você quer tornar a EditText que está `invisible` para `visible`?

Comment: Quase isso... eu quero que, ao abrir o arquivo xml como activity, ele ja inicie invisible, poreem, quando eu marcar a radiobutton, ele apareça

Answer (score 1):

A visibilidade de uma *View* pode ser indicada usando o método *JAVA* `setVisibility()` ou o atributo *XML* `android.visibility`.

Para que a sua *EditText* inicialize como invisível faça:

No *XML*

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/minhaEditText"
    ....
    ....
    android:visibility="invisible"
    ..../>
```

Ou no *JAVA*
No método `onCreate()`

```
EditText minhaEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minhaEditText);
minhaEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Quando quiser que ela volte a ser visivel:

```
minhaEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você quer que o EditText esteja NULO ou esteja sem conteúdo escrito nele?
Se for sem conteúdo basta fazer algo do tipo:

```
editText.setText("");
```

Isso vai fazer com que o conteúdo do EditText fique em branco.

Comment: Quero que ele ja inicie nulo, para que quando eu marque uma radiobutton, ele fique visivel